# File lock on created image?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm in the process of hunting down a resource leak in a service and am curious whether or not the following code in fact could be locking this file after it's created. It appears that maybe it's being locked because it's deleted after it's opened, then saved again?

**edit in response to comments:**

The file is being accessed later and returns an IOException with the message stating that the file cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process.

Also, is the "img = new Bitmap(...) not actually accessing the file when it's created? Or am I off on that?

```
 using (Image img = new Bitmap(imgPath))
 {
     path = m_fpService.GetProcessedPath(irec, true);
     if (File.Exists(imgPath))
     {
         File.Delete(imgPath);
     }

     img.RotateFlip((RotateFlipType)adjustedRotation);
     img.Save(imgPath);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locked?"  Is another downstream file operation failing?

Comment: Don't post "maybe", post the exception you get.  If there is no exception then there is no question.

Comment: The maybe was the "why" not whether or not it was happening. Sorry for not being clear in the original post.

Comment: I believe your creating an exclusive lock on the bitmap with Image img = new Bitmap(imgPath)

Comment: @coltech - Wouldn't that lock be released after the using block?

Comment: @mbeckish That's what I had thought and was debating with a coworker.

Comment: @mbeckish - That is correct, but it looks like you are trying to delete and re-save the image within your using block. Perhaps Image img = new Bitmap(imgPath).Clone() would work?

Comment: @coltech Ahhh, worth a try for sure.

Comment: @Jon Ownbey - Is the exception being raised within this using block, or later?

Comment: @mbeckish It's happening later in a completely different service. This particular service/app is finished by then. It's a resource leak somewhere and this is what appears to be the most likely culprit currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f.aspx)

> The file name and path can be relative to the application or an
>   absolute path. Use this constructor to open images with the following
>   file formats: BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF. For more information
>   about supported formats, see Types of Bitmaps. The file remains locked
>   until the Bitmap is disposed.

Not sure why that is but I suppose the `Bitmap` class can lazy-load parts of the file. For that feature, it needs access after the constructor has run.

You can use the Stream-taking overload of the constructor, and close the stream at a time of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was working with the understanding that the using statement would dispose of the Bitmap once it completed.

Comment: It does, but while inside of the using block, the lock is still held.

Comment: @Jon Ownbey - What was the issue?  Was it a timing issue where the other app was trying to access the bitmap before this code completed the using block?

Comment: @mbeckish - Yep the actual problem was with a different app not releasing the file before my service picked it up. Thanks for all the help!